# Presenting view controller function not being called iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

For this problem, the view controller in which this code is run is in the Login.storyboard IB file.  The view controller I am trying to present is in the Main.storyboard IB file.  The code below is what I'm using to transition from one view controller to another.

```
func presentNextView() {
    let mainSb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let screenAfterLogin: UIViewController = mainSb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainContainerView") as! UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(screenAfterLogin, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Running the application, I set 3 breakpoints on the 3 lines executed in the presentNextView function.  Line one is called, line two is called, but line three is NOT called, and the next screen is not presented.  Is there something wrong with xCode at the moment?

Checkout the project on github: https://github.com/joshuarcher/RecallBeta

Problem lies in file "HardLoginViewController.swift"

Comment: Just to make sure..Do you have given "MainContainerView" as storyboard identifier in inspector window of storyboard.

Comment: Yes, it's declared as Storyboard ID

Answer (score 0):

```
func presentNextView() {

    let mainSb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let screenAfterLogin: SecondVC = mainSb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as SecondVC
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: screenAfterLogin)
    presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why embed it in a navigation controller?

Comment: Also, now the line "let navigationController..." is not being called

Comment: are getting something like this "view is not in the window hierarchy!"

Comment: Nope, it simply does not update the view of the screen to the next viewcontroller

Comment: If your current view controller is not embedded in Navigation Controller and if you try to present new view controller, it will generate "view is not in the window hierarchy!" warning, which results into no change in screen. To make it work you have to embed into navigation controller either parent or presentingviewcontroller, and i am sure you would be able to see your next controller.

Comment: Still not running the 3rd or 4th line in the function.  If you're curious, and I would greatly appreciate your help, you can checkout the xcodeproject on gitHub at [link](https://github.com/joshuarcher/RecallBeta).  The issue is in the swift file HardLoginViewController.swift in the Login folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76683/discussion-between-joshua-archer-and-user3680929).

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        presentNextView()
    }

    func presentNextView() {
        let mainSb: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let screenAfterLogin: SecondVC = mainSb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as SecondVC
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: screenAfterLogin)
        presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.title="Second Screen"
    }
}
```